# Looping the characters of a line to get each one but having IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, range, line

I have the following code

```
import sys

from collections import defaultdict

filename = sys.argv[1]

g = defaultdict(list)

l = 0

with open(filename) as graph_file:
    for line in graph_file:
        for pos in line:
            g[l].append(pos[0])
            g[l].append(pos[1])

            g[l+1].append(pos[1])
            g[l+1].append(pos[2])

        l = l+1

for i in g.keys():
    if '\n' in g[i]:
        g[i].remove('\n')

for i in g.keys():
    print (i, g[i])
```

When I use the cmd to run the program, I have the following error and I can't figure why.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in 
    g[l].append(pos[1])
IndexError: string index out of range

I know what it means, but I can't understand why it happens. The text file that I'm trying to open is the following:

```
ATA
GTG
TAC
ACC
AAG
CCA
TGG
GTA
TAT
ATG
TGT
AGT
GGA
GAC
ACT
CTT
TTC
CAA
TCA
CAT
```

Comment: What is the output of `print pos`. Looks like your first row might be a space or something.

Comment: I will suggest learning to use a Debugger like the PyCharm's Debugger tool. Learn how to debug program will help you understand where your problem is and therefore to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that when you loop over with `for pos in line`, you are essentially looping over `for pos in 'ATA'`, taking the first line. Thus, `pos` first gets assigned to `'A'`, triggering an error when you try to access the 2nd item in it—you are looping once too many.

Instead, change your code to the following:

```
import sys

from collections import defaultdict

filename = sys.argv[1]

g = defaultdict(list)

l = 0

with open(filename) as graph_file:
    for line in graph_file:
         g[l].append(line[0])
         g[l].append(line[1])
         g[l+1].append(line[1])
         g[l+1].append(line[2])

         l = l+1

for i in g.keys():
    if '\n' in g[i]:
        g[i].remove('\n')

for i in g.keys():
    print (i, g[i])
```

---

```
bash-3.2$ python foo.py foo.txt
(0, ['A', 'T'])
(1, ['T', 'A', 'G', 'T'])
(2, ['T', 'G', 'T', 'A'])
(3, ['A', 'C', 'A', 'C'])
(4, ['C', 'C', 'A', 'A'])
(5, ['A', 'G', 'C', 'C'])
(6, ['C', 'A', 'T', 'G'])
(7, ['G', 'G', 'G', 'T'])
(8, ['T', 'A', 'T', 'A'])
(9, ['A', 'T', 'A', 'T'])
(10, ['T', 'G', 'T', 'G'])
(11, ['G', 'T', 'A', 'G'])
(12, ['G', 'T', 'G', 'G'])
(13, ['G', 'A', 'G', 'A'])
(14, ['A', 'C', 'A', 'C'])
(15, ['C', 'T', 'C', 'T'])
(16, ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T'])
(17, ['T', 'C', 'C', 'A'])
(18, ['A', 'A', 'T', 'C'])
(19, ['C', 'A', 'C', 'A'])
(20, ['A', 'T'])
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Thank you I think I got what you mean :)

Still, when I run the program now I get a new error and I think it has to do with the way I read or open the file but I don't know gow to fix it.. :

NameError: name 'ATA' is not defined

ATA is the first line of my txt file